# Understanding the language of pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

In most of the dictionaries apart from the meaning of the word, there is also a list of characters that tell how to pronounce the word.
Is there a specific name for those things?   How to understand them?
**For example in the below image:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Many dictionaries use their own systems to indicate pronunciations, though such individual schemes tend to have similarities. The most serious and rigorous system is [the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

Answer (score -1):

It's called the **Phonetic Alphabet** and you can find a full description here in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).